# AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'upload_from_filename'

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform

I'm using Python 2.7.9 on Linux and I am following Google's [example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/gcp-integration) on Google-Cloud Server SDK. My goal is to upload an image to Google Cloud Platform, but I'm getting the error below.

```
File "/home/pi/test.py", line 15, in <module>
  zebraBlob.upload_from_filename(filename='/home/pi/Pictures/testimg.jpg')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute
  'upload_from_filename'
```

Code:

```
from firebase import firebase
from google.cloud import storage
import os

firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://motion-detector-234.firebaseio.com', None)
storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('Motion Detector-8gf5445fgeeea.json')

bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('motion-detector-210fds717.appspot.com')
print ('bucket', bucket) // output: bucket, motion-detector-210717.appspot.com

zebraBlob = bucket.get_blob('testimg.jpg')
print(zebraBlob) // output: None

zebraBlob.upload_from_filename(filename='/home/pi/Pictures/testimg.jpg')
```

How can it be resolved?

Comment: What does your `bucket.get_blob('testimg.jpg')` returns ? The error tells you zebraBlob is `None` (no value) after executing the get_blob.

Comment: May be your jpeg file is testing.jpg. Could it be a typo?

Comment: @Florian it returns 'None' - what am I missing?

Comment: I added print to the code so you can see the output.

Comment: @Json, yes that's the point. You are using `get_blob('testimg.jpg')` on your `bucket` object. You store the result in zebraBlob, and then you try to call `upload_from_filename(...)` on your `zebraBlob`. But your `zebraBlob` is `None`, so it doesn't have the `upload_from_filename` method.

Comment: @Florain thanks for the info. please post this as an answer and I'll submit a new question about the 'None'  issue.

Answer (score 9):

To make it work you should simply write `zebraBlob = bucket.blob('testimg.jpg')` instead of `zebraBlob = bucket.get_blob('testimg.jpg')`

Answer (score 0):

Came across the same issue and only solved it by **creating** another image from the **Google Cloud Console first** (navigate to your bucket and click "*Upload file*").

Once it has been made it seems to work fine and uploads the new image, replacing the other one.

ps you can rename the image on console like [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/renaming-copying-moving-objects)

If I figure out how to just create a new file without doing this first I will update this post, if anyone else knows already please feel free to inbox me to update it :)